# Newly setup Centos 6 server, cloning from .GIT as user other than ROOT

Tags: linux, apache, ssh, permissions, centos

Apologies for being so new and lost, i'm brand new to all of this and the more I search the more I feel I'm getting closer, but then realize i'm lost.

I setup a CentOS 6 server on an Amazon E2 instance, Apache installed & configured, etc.

My problem is that I've begun doing things using the **root** user, which I've been reading is bad.

I have a .GIT repository of a WordPress website that I cloned to this server as root user, and for the most part everything is fine, but then I began noticing problems.

First off, the entire directory was owned by root since that was the user I used to clone, so WordPress installation couldn't write to files... i've since fixed this by running `Chown -R /var/www/html` so that "**apache**" owns the directory.  This is a temporary fix since it's now possible for WordPress to write to the .htaccess file to remedy 404 errors, however I've heard it's bad for Apache to own your web folder as it could be a security risk?

Now i'm attempting to go back and make things right, i've created a user named "**sysadmin**", and added it to a group called "**wheel**".  From my understanding my username should match the group permissions to that of Apache?   This is where i'm lost and not sure where to continue..

If someone could at least point me in the right direction that would be great.

Thank you!

Comment: What about [this](http://serverfault.com/questions/224560/best-permissions-ownership-for-apache-document-root) link, which describes how to set permissions for apache document root

Comment: Please avoid cross-posting questions to multiple SE sites.